# Is the matrix inequality $P > Q \geq 0$ implies $P^2 > Q^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $P$ and $Q$ are positive definite and positive semi-definite, respectively, and both are symmetric. Then, is it true that
\begin{equation}
   P > Q \;\; \Longrightarrow \;\; P^2 > Q^2 \;\;?
\end{equation}
 (I know that both $P^2 > 0$ and $Q^2 \geq 0$ are obviously true).
 Can anyone provide a counter example if the statement is not true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a satisfactory answer, but with $P=\begin{bmatrix}13 & -6 \\ -6 & 13 \end{bmatrix}, Q= \begin{bmatrix}10 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ one finds that
$P>Q \ge 0$, but $P^2 \not> Q^2$.

$\lambda(P) = \{7, 19\}$, $\lambda(P-Q) = \{ 8 \pm \sqrt{61} \}$,$\lambda(P^2-Q^2) = \{ 155 \pm 2 \sqrt{6709}\} $. ($\sqrt{6709}> \sqrt{6561} = 81$, hence the smallest eigenvalue of $P^2-Q^2$ is negative).